# how to connect label node with compute node without the route to label node in ibm app connect?

Tags: ibm-app-connect

I want to connect the label nodes with compute node only without the route to label node

ibm app connect enterprise how to connect label node with compute node? I've searched at the document alot but I have found nothing at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [PROPAGATE TO LABEL](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/12.0?topic=statements-propagate-statement) statement in your compute node.